# Processing P2D in eclipse noSuchMethodError glVertexAttribPointer(IIIZILjava/nio/Buffer;)

Tags: eclipse, opengl, processing, java

I'm trying to run a processing sketch in eclipse. I've been doing this for quite a while, but have only recently updated to 2.1.
The sketch runs fine when running the software mode. But when I try to use the P2D mode I get the error below.
I have included all the jogl jars from the processing folder. I'm not sure if I should add native libraries though, I can't seem to find them.

> Exception in thread "Animation Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.media.opengl.GL2ES2.glVertexAttribPointer(IIIZILjava/nio/Buffer;)V
>       at com.jogamp.common.util.awt.AWTEDTExecutor.invoke(AWTEDTExecutor.java:58)
>       at jogamp.opengl.awt.AWTThreadingPlugin.invokeOnOpenGLThread(AWTThreadingPlugin.java:103)
>       at jogamp.opengl.ThreadingImpl.invokeOnOpenGLThread(ThreadingImpl.java:206)
>       at javax.media.opengl.Threading.invokeOnOpenGLThread(Threading.java:172)
>       at javax.media.opengl.Threading.invoke(Threading.java:191)
>       at javax.media.opengl.awt.GLCanvas.display(GLCanvas.java:492)
>       at processing.opengl.PGL.requestDraw(PGL.java:1155)
>       at processing.opengl.PGraphicsOpenGL.requestDraw(PGraphicsOpenGL.java:1602)
>       at processing.core.PApplet.run(PApplet.java:2141)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>   Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.media.opengl.GL2ES2.glVertexAttribPointer(IIIZILjava/nio/Buffer;)V
>       at processing.opengl.PGL.vertexAttribPointer(PGL.java:3318)
>       at processing.opengl.PGL.drawTexture2D(PGL.java:1594)
>       at processing.opengl.PGL.drawTexture(PGL.java:1507)
>       at processing.opengl.PGL.endDraw(PGL.java:1110)
>       at processing.opengl.PGraphicsOpenGL.endOnscreenDraw(PGraphicsOpenGL.java:5974)
>       at processing.opengl.PGraphicsOpenGL.endDraw(PGraphicsOpenGL.java:1681)
>       at processing.core.PApplet.handleDraw(PApplet.java:2290)
>       at processing.opengl.PGL$PGLListener.display(PGL.java:2643)
>       at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.displayImpl(GLDrawableHelper.java:590)
>       at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.display(GLDrawableHelper.java:574)
>       at javax.media.opengl.awt.GLCanvas$9.run(GLCanvas.java:1218)
>       at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.invokeGLImpl(GLDrawableHelper.java:1036)
>       at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.invokeGL(GLDrawableHelper.java:911)
>       at javax.media.opengl.awt.GLCanvas$10.run(GLCanvas.java:1229)
>       at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: Try https://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/Downloading_and_installing_JOGL , maybe you have missed something. Since you say you just upgraded your version, the error must be made there.

Comment: https://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/Setting_up_a_JogAmp_project_in_your_favorite_IDE#Maven , another usefull page.

Comment: Same problem here (Eclipse, JOGL2 using a GL2ES2 context). The method seems to support only two alternative parameters; specifying your data using a `GLArrayData` implementation, or passing a `long` to represent a pointer to your buffer. Both these implementations require pointer data, and I'm not too sure at this point where it can be taken from.

Comment: I've just given it some thought, and it probably expects the data to reside in a a VBO. I'll see if this works.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that the GLES20 function `glVertexAttribPointer(int indx, int size, int type, boolean normalized, int stride, Buffer buf)` is not available within JOGL's GL2ES2 API.

It has instead been replaced with `glVertexAttribPointer(int indx, int size, int type, boolean normalized, int stride, long ptr_buffer_offset)`.

The high level methodology associated with it's usage is as follows, after compiling and linking your attribute-dependent shaders within a program:

1. Load your vertices into a Vertex Buffer Object (VBO).
2. Instantiate a corresponding Index Buffer Object, used to inform OpenGL
   of the order in which the VBO vertices need to be iterated through.
3. Bind to the VBO.
4. Define your call to `glVertexAttribPointer`, which informs OpenGL of the structure of your vertex data.
5. Enable the attribute using `glEnableVertexAttribArray`.
6. Bind to your Index Buffer Object.
7. Use `glDrawElements` to draw your VBO vertices in the order specified by your IBO.
8. Unbind from the IBO.
9. Disable the attribute.
10. Unbind from your VBO.

`ptr_buffer_offset` then references the internal offset within that bound buffer, therefore to read from the beginning of the buffer you can just specify `0L`. The same goes for for your call to `glDrawElements`.